# ProgramNotRecognizedError: The provided program name [mplCandyGuard] is not recognized in the [devnet] cluster

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, nft, mint, candy-machine-v3

I am trying to mint NFTs from a candy machine v3 using the umi library as shown in this https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/minting . I am using the following code -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Metaplex, walletAdapterIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
 some,
 generateSigner,
 transactionBuilder,
 } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import  {mintV2}  from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";
import { setComputeUnitLimit } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-essentials";
import {
  Connection,
  } from "@solana/web3.js";

 const MintNFT = () => {
 const { publicKey, wallet } = useWallet();
 const [nft, setNft] = useState(null);
 const umi = useMemo(
    () => createUmi(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOLANA_RPC_HOST),
    []
   );
   const connection = useMemo(
   () => new Connection(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOLANA_RPC_HOST, "confirmed"),
[]
  );
       const candyMachineAddress = new PublicKey(
       process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_ID
      );
     const metaplex = useMemo(
  () => Metaplex.make(connection).use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet)),
   [connection, wallet]
   );
  let candyMachine;
  let walletBalance;
 const onClick = async () => {
// Here the actual mint happens. Depending on the guards that you are using you have to run some pre validation beforehand
// Read more: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/minting#minting-with-pre-validation
// read candy machine state from chain
candyMachine = await metaplex
  .candyMachines()
  .findByAddress({ address: candyMachineAddress });
console.log(candyMachine);
await transactionBuilder()
  .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
  .add(
    mintV2(umi, {
      candyMachine: candyMachine.address,
      publicKey,
      collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMintAddress,
      collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authorityAddress,
      mintArgs: {
        mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
        solPayment: some({ destination: candyMachine.authorityAddress }),
      },
    })
  )
  .sendAndConfirm(umi);
  };

  return (
   <div>
  <div>Here we mint the NFT</div>
  <button
    className="bg-blue-400 text-sm text-white rounded-full hover:bg-blue-600 m-0 mt-4 py-2 px-8"
    onClick={onClick}
    
  >
    mint NFT
  </button>
  {nft && (
    <div className={styles.nftPreview}>
      <h1>{nft.name}</h1>
      <img
        src={nft?.json?.image || "/fallbackImage.jpg"}
        alt="The downloaded illustration of the provided NFT address."
      />
    </div>
   )}
   </div>
   );
   }

   export default MintNFT
```

but on clicking the Mint NFT button I am getting the following error -
caught (in promise) ProgramNotRecognizedError: The provided program name [mplCandyGuard] is not recognized in the [devnet] cluster. Did you forget to register this program? If so, you may use "context.programs.add(myProgram)" to fix this.

Source: SDK
Can somebody please suggest what is wrong and how to rectify the error?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I can not see in your code snippet how you initialise umi, but what you basically need to do to register the guard program is:

umi.use(mplCandyMachine())

In my personal mint ui implementation the umi definition currently looks like this

const umi = createUmi(endpoint)
.use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
.use(mplTokenMetadata())
.use(mplCandyMachine())

- walletAdapterIdentity is needed for the browser wallets to work.
- mplTokenMetadata To load the nft metadata after the mint.
- mplCandyMachine to register the candy guard and candy machine
  programs

Please note, that you should not need @metaplex-foundation/js when using umi. All functions can be replaced with nether new modules. (This can be relevant for size / speed improvements)

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP, but for Fungible tokens. This is was because I didnt not use mplCandyMachine for the fungible token creation and mint. After adding it to both the token creation and mint, it worked. TO be honest, I dont know why mplCandyMachine is needed for Fungible tokens but keeping it for now